# Rails - Radio Buttons for collection sets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following which outputs a select box:

```
<%= f.label :request_type_id %><br />
<% requestTypes = RequestType.all %>
<%= f.collection_select :request_type_id, requestTypes, :id, :title, :prompt => true %>
```

What is the rails method to instead output Radio Buttons?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For radio buttons you have to iterate yourself and output every radio button and its label. It's really easy in fact.

```
<% RequestType.all.each do |rt| %>
  <%= f.radio_button :request_type_id, rt.id %>
  <%= f.label :request_type_id, rt.title %>
<% end %>
```

Or in [haml](http://haml.info/) in case it's preferred over erb:

```
- RequestType.all.each do |rt|
    = f.radio_button :request_type_id, rt.id
    = f.label :request_type_id, rt.title
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked great but I did need to work with the label FOR to make it match the radio button.

Comment: @AnApprentice - Did some searching for the same thing and found this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4921732/247763

Comment: Any idea how to do this, but with fixed values. I mean instead of `Model..all.each`, you have something like `for i in 0..5`?

Answer (score 11):

In Rails 4 there is a [collection_radio_buttons](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/collection_radio_buttons) for this:

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :request_type_id, RequestType.all, :id, :title %>
```

Answer (score 4):

An example how to use `f.collection_radio_buttons` with an `Enum` as a collection:

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :reason, MyEnum.statuses.map {|k,v| [k,k]}, :first, :last do |b| %>
  <div class='your-class'>
    <%= b.radio_button %>
    <%= b.label %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) gem:

In controller:

```
@request_types = RequestType.all
```

In a form:

```
<%= f.association :request_type, collection: @request_types, as: :radio_buttons %>
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is a default option in Rails to achieve this; luckily plugins are your friend and I think that what you want is very easy with [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form).

Answer (score -1):

Here's your radio button you can the below as such :-

```
<%= f.radio_button:request_type_id,'1',{"id","title"} %>id  
<%= f.radio_button:request_type_id,'2',{"id","title"} %>title
```