# Associating label and radio button in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm using Rails 2.3.8. My code:

```
<%= f.radio_button :status, "draft" %>
<%= f.label :status, "Draft" %>
<%= f.radio_button :status, "published" %>
<%= f.label :status, "Published" %>
```

Output:

```
<input id="shop_status_draft" name="shop[status]" type="radio" value="draft" />
<label for="shop_status">Draft</label>
<input checked="checked" id="shop_status_published" name="shop[status]" type="radio" value="published" />
<label for="shop_status">Published</label>
```

Obviously the `label` isn't associating with my radio buttons correctly. I want to make the `label` same as radio button `id`. How can I correct that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try this

```
<%= f.radio_button :status, "draft" %>
<%= f.label :status, "Draft", :value => "draft" %>
<%= f.radio_button :status, "published" %>
<%= f.label :status, "Published", :value => "published" %>
```

Comment: I am new to RoR and I find formtastic way easier to handle form views. You may want to give it a try : https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you! In my case the values were `true` and `false` and it worked just fine. I also added a main label at the top for the question text `<%= f.label :status, "Status:" %>`.

Comment: I've been struggling with this forever, especially when I want capybara to `choose 'Field name'`. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, where I was looping through plans:

```
<% @plans.each do |plan| %>
    <%= radio_button_tag :plan_id, plan.id %> 
    <%= label_tag 'plan_id_' + plan.id.to_s, plan.name %>
<% end %>
```