# Associating label and radio button in HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, haml

I have a similar question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921277/associating-label-and-radio-button-in-rails) but I can't figure out how to do it in HAML.

My code is, at the moment:

```
.col-sm-10.radio-toolbar
   - YearGroup.all.each do |year_group|
    = f.label dom_id(year_group), year_group.name
    = f.radio_button :year_group_id, year_group.name
```

Which gives me, in html:

```
<div class="col-sm-10 radio-toolbar">
    <label for="test_year_group_1"></label>
    <input id="test_year_group_id_as" type="radio" name="test[year_group_id]" value="AS"></input>
    <label for="test_year_group_2"></label>
    <input id="test_year_group_id_a2" type="radio" name="test[year_group_id]" value="A2"></input>
</div>
```

As you can see, the label for has a number, whereas the input id has as or a2. How can I add a value to the label so that it will be the same as the id on the input?

Comment: As I said in the first line of the question, that didn't help as my problem is with the HAML

Comment: It's all the same in ham, just add `value: 'AS'` to your label call.

Comment: Because it was an .each loop I couldn't just add the value to it...I don't think?

Comment: Why not? HAML does not alter the helpers in any way, you can use them same way as in ERB.  `= f.label dom_id(year_group), year_group.name, value: year_group.name`

Comment: Ahh, ok, I see what you mean, sorry. Yes, that does work, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else comes across this problem, I solved it by changing it to:

```
.col-sm-10.radio-toolbar
  - YearGroup.all.each do |year_group|
    = f.label dom_id(year_group), year_group.name
    = f.radio_button :year_group, year_group.id
```

Which forced the HTML of the for label and id of the input to be the same.

Or see BrioSatse's answers in the comments....