# Multiple Radio buttons that store a value - Rails Simple Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm sure this is something annoyingly simple but I'm missing it. I'm trying to create multiple radio buttons in a table, using simple form that then, instead of storing the value "true" they store the value of the particular radio button in the database.

Here's my code:

```
<%= render layout: 'form' do |f| %>
<h1>Quotes</h1>
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

<table class="table">
  <thead>
<tr>
  <th>Indemnity Limit</th>
  <th>Commercial<br/>Insurance</th>
</tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<tr>
  <td>£1,000,000</td>
  <td><%= f.radio_button :quote, checked: true, value: "£57.50", input_html: { value: '£57.50' } %>£57.50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>£2,000,000</td>
  <td><%= f.radio_button :quote, label: '£74.00', value: "£74.00" %>£74.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>£3,000,000</td>
  <td><%= f.radio_button :quote, id: '3', label: '£85.00', value: "£85.00" %>85.00</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>£5,000,000</td>
  <td><%= f.radio_button :quote, label: '£101.50', value: "£101.50" %>£101.50</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

I'm trying to achieve this:

[image: Multiple radio buttons]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rails - Radio Buttons for collection sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151650/rails-radio-buttons-for-collection-sets)

You need to specify them as such:

```
<%= f.radio_button :quote, '35.00' %>
```

The first value is the attribute you're updating, and the second is the value that will be sent if selected.

If the value is an integer rather than a string, remove the quotes.

Comment: Doesn't work using Simple Form, throws the error "invalid byte sequence in UTF-8"

Comment: Just came back to this and realised it was the "checked: true" causing the invalid byte sequence error. It needed to be after the value. Your solution worked thanks!

Comment: Happy to help :)